# Is "heartfelt" reserved for sad moments, or can it be used for happy ones?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, word-usage, adjectives

I'm writing an email about something nice (a newborn child), and was about to use the word "heartfelt". Just then, I noticed I may have heard the word almost exclusively in the context of a sad situation (condolence).

Is there a good reason for my hesitation, or is "heartfelt" appropriate in either situation? If not, what's a better choice of a word? How about "heartily"?

Comment: Though by definition there is no such negative connotation, collocation/ usage seems to have rendered it so. I think *heartiest* (even *hearty*) is a more popular adjective in the context. *Heartfelt* collocates more in an unhappy context, yes.

Comment: This web page suggests that "heartfelt" is an appropriate expression to use to congratulate someone: http://www.words-to-use.com/words/congratulations/ It also offers many other fixed phrases which you could use instead, if you still feel uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Heartfelt" *can* be used to express positive feelings:

> Her joy was truly heartfelt!
>
> You have our heartfelt thanks.

But it is most commonly associated with sorrow or grief. When in doubt, choose a different word.

Answer (score 0):

You may well be right. *Sincere* would be a neutral alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Heartfelt is most appropriately a connotation to show the state of mind whether it is joy extremely felt or a sorrow moment of grief. It is a state of mind how mind accepts the reaction.